# Find the minimum of integral

Tags: integration, calculus-of-variations

For $g(x):\Bbb R \rightarrow [0,\infty],$ if  $$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} g(x)\, dx= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} x^2g(x)\, dx=C$$
find the minimum value of $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \ln(g(x))g(x)\, dx$.

Would you give me some hint to this?

Thank you.

Comment: Use Lagrange multipliers.

Comment: I tried with locally constant functions of the form $$f(x)=\cases{k & if $x \in [a;b]$ \\ 0 & otherwise}$$ and got that there is no minimum. You can get arbitrarily low to $- \infty$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We want to minimize the functional
$$
S[g]=\int_{\mathbb R} g(x)\ln(g(x))\, dx \tag{1}
$$
subject to the constraints
$$
\int_{\mathbb R} g(x)\, dx=C,\qquad \int_{\mathbb R} x^2g(x)\, dx=C. \tag{2}
$$
Using the method of [Lagrange multipliers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_multiplier), this is equivalent to finding the stationary point(s) of the modified functional
$$
\tilde{S}[g,\lambda,\mu]=\int_{\mathbb R} g(x)\ln(g(x))\,dx+\lambda\left(\int_{\mathbb R} g(x)\, dx-C\right)+\mu\left(\int_{\mathbb R} x^2g(x)\, dx-C\right). \tag{3}
$$
The [Euler-Lagrange equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Lagrange_equation) for $\tilde{S}$ is
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial g}\left[g(x)\ln(g(x))+\lambda g(x)+\mu x^2g(x)\right]=0 
$$
$$
\implies \ln(g(x))+1+\lambda+\mu x^2=0
$$
$$\implies g(x)=e^{-1-\lambda-\mu x^2}, 
\tag{4}
$$
showing that $g$ is a Gaussian function. It is a straightforward calculation to determine the parameters $\lambda$ and $\mu$ using the constraints $(2)$. The final result is
$$
g(x)=\frac{C}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}}. \tag{5}
$$
Plugging $(5)$ into $(1)$, we obtain, after another straightforward calculation, the minimum value of $S[g]$:
$$
S_{\min}=-\frac{C}{2}\left(\ln(2\pi)+1\right). \tag{6}
$$